# Calling sub with 2 parameters defined

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to call a sub in my main and basically fill another column with this sub. But I am getting a syntax error. Why is this?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim mystring As String, i As Long, asciinum As String, f As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For f = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
            mystring = .Cells(f, "I").Value2
            prueba1 (mystring, f)
        Next f
    End With
End Sub

Sub prueba1(mystring, index As Long)
Dim i As Long, asciinum As String

            For i = 1 To Len(mystring)
                asciinum = LCase(Mid(mystring, i, 1))
                If asciinum Like "[aeiou]" Then
                    .Cells(index, "M") = "First Vowel " + asciinum
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `prueba1 (mystring, f)` should be `prueba1 mystring, f` and `prueba1(mystring, index As Long)` should be `prueba1(mystring AS STRING, index As Long)`

Comment: Haha thanks man! you are everywhere

Comment: There is no parent worksheet in a With ... End With in prueba1 but you are using `.Cells` instead of `Cells`.

Comment: See [Procedure Calls](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201704071555264315385) on Documentation.SO for the exact reason behind your syntax error. TL;DR: `pruebal (mystring, f)` is being evaluated as a value for the first argument, and there is no 2nd argument. Drop the parentheses when calling a procedure you don't need a return value for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `prueba1 (mystring, f)` should be `prueba1 mystring, f`
- `prueba1(mystring, index As Long)` should be `prueba1(mystring AS STRING, index As Long)`
- There is no parent worksheet in a With ... End With in prueba1 but you are using `.Cells` instead of `Cells`. At a minimum, it should be `Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(index, "M") = "First Vowel " + asciinum`

Comment: I also wonder why OP declares `mystring` as an implicit variant, but `index` as an explicit `Long`. But, meh.